# How to add an interactive notification badge to my webpage?

Tags: javascript, css, html, web, notifications

I'm currently working on a website, and I wanted to add a "news" section, which will display an Apple-style notification badge when there is a new article.  How to I make it so the badge disappears, after the user clicks on the "news" button, and stays hidden?

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle with what you've done so far?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question precisely:

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#news" class="nav">News</a><span class="badge">2</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Javascript (requires jQuery)**

```
$('.nav').on('click', function(){
    $('.badge').hide()
})
```

It will stay hidden alright. :)